# Xcode 12 Error: Multiple commands produce AccessibilityResources.bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode12

Building my react native project from Xcode gives the error below;

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT-grjkuplqgvolxebnwadcuuhwkdak/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PROJECT/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle':
1) Target 'React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources' has create directory command with output '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT-grjkuplqgvolxebnwadcuuhwkdak/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PROJECT/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'
2) Target 'React-Core.common-CoreModulesHeaders-AccessibilityResources' has create directory command with output '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT-grjkuplqgvolxebnwadcuuhwkdak/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/PROJECT/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'
```

I check other answers for 'multiple commands produce' error but no luck so far. They are mostly related to vector-icons though.

How do I fix this error for AccessibilityResources?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Removing `React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources` from target in `Podfile` fixed the issue.

```
...
use_flipper!
post_install do |installer|
  flipper_post_install(installer)

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
...
```

Comment: I understand this is a workaround but has anybody else found a permanent solution?

Answer (score 31):

Deleting `React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources` in the Pods project worked for me. Followed the answer from: [this possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63082833/how-to-fix-react-native-app-not-building-for-ios)

[image: Pod deletion example]

Comment: When you should do that every build

Comment: From what I understand, and I could be wrong here, every team you update your pods.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you @likeachamp. It worked, on XCode 13 I added a little bit modified:

```
...
post_install do |installer|
  flipper_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "React-Core-AccessibilityResources"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
```