# How do I archive Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am currently having issues when attempting to archive my project in Xcode. The following error below appears when archiving:

[image: Error]

The link [Xcode 12 Error: Multiple commands produce AccessibilityResources.bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040154/xcode-12-error-multiple-commands-produce-accessibilityresources-bundle) mentions to remove React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources from my target but I do not have this under my target. Can someone please assist?

I am using Xcode version 12.1.

This is what I have in the workspace settings:

[image]

Thank you.

I changed the derived data location but still getting the same error:

[image]

I am now seeing the below error after updating my Podfile.

Current error:
[image]

Updated Podfile:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the below solution.

Initially clean the build cache data with the below steps:

1. You can go to File > Workspace Settings if you are in a workspace environment or File > Project Settings for a regular project environment.
2. Then click over the little grey arrow under the Derived data section and select your project folder and close the workspace and Xcode then delete the project directory from the derived data directory.
3. Open the workspace again in Xcode and clean and rebuild the project.

Also, make sure that you have applied pod install after the package installation.

Then, open workspace and set the active scheme as Any ios Device (arm64, armv7)

1. Click on Project from top Xcode Menu
2. Then select Archive.

Have a break till the Archive process completes.

Remove the below lines from PodFile:

```
use_flipper!()
post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
end
```

and do pod install in ios directory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do I need to change the Derived Data from 'Default Location'? I'm unable to select my project folder when clicking the grey arrow.

Comment: I changed the location to my project folder and followed your steps after but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @AJDee, Do you use the flipper ?

Comment: I don't know what that is. I'm fairly new to Xcode but I don't think I'm using that.

Comment: Okay!, Can you share PodFile code in ios directory?

Comment: Podfile added above. Thanks

Comment: @AJDee, I have updated the answer please have a look

Comment: Unfortunately, updating the Podfile as above and running pod install didn't help. I am still seeing the same problem

Comment: Can someone please assist with this?

Comment: after making comments on those lines have you followed all the above steps for removing the derived data and re-build project again ?

Comment: I followed your steps above but I am still getting the same error. Please see my updated Podfile. Is this correct?

Comment: You have not done it properly I have updated my answer please remove those lines and do pod install again and do a clean build and run again

Comment: Thanks. I am now having an issue where the error "...library not found for -lboringssl-grpc" appears when archiving. I have tried removing Firebase/Firestore from my Podfile and running pod install. That causes the error "...library not found for - ldoubleconversion". I have tried removing the quotes from the library search paths. That doesn't help. I'm definitely sure I'm opening the workspace and not the project. I really don't know what to do here.

Comment: Any ideas on what I may need to do in order to fix this? I am completely stuck. Thanks

Comment: I've noticed that if I set the Build System to New Build System Default in Workspace settings I still get the same error as before Multiple commands produce... AccessibilityResources.bundle....Changing this to Legacy gives me the "...library not found for -lboringssl-grpc..." error. Can someone please help here?

Comment: I am now facing the error: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code. This is after changing to New Build System Default and attempting to remove my initial error "Multiple commands produce... AccessibilityResources.bundle.." by updating my Podfile as above

Comment: can you please attach the image of the error you are getting

Comment: Any ideas on what I may need to do here please?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on what may be causing this error? Thanks

Comment: Which files can you see in the copy bundle resources in build phase of your ios project ?

Comment: All my screen js files I have created, the .storyboard file, the package.json and package-lock.json files, .xcworkspace file and .xcassets file.

Comment: I removed the files package.json, package-lock.json and .xcworkspace but unfortunately that didn't resolve the issue. The same error popped up. I have changed the run script in Bundle React Native code and images to export NODE_BINARY=$(which node) before the .sh script but that didn't help. Still same error seeing.

Comment: @AJDee, make sure you should only have the ios project-related files in the ios directory other might lead to major issues like you are facing now.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed all except storyboard and xcassets file but still seeing the same error after re-building.

Comment: Have you also tried to delete the derived data ?

Comment: which file you are selecting while opening the project in xcode ?

Comment: I use command line 'open Project.xcworskspace' in the ios folder

Comment: Okay that's perfect.

Comment: Could it be due to my xcode? Although, a new project seems to archive fine.

Comment: May be but if you have made some changes at native level might also affect to you at the time of creating and running build

Comment: Have a try by creating a new project and moving the logic from the old app to the new app.