# Xcode 13.2.1 when I try to archive my react native project from xcode it gives error Multiple commands produce. I tried almost every solution

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, xcode13.2

**Multiple commands produce** '/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BehzadPhtographyProjct-hibcbeuckyuxhmdaockdldhnuyen/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BehzadPhtographyProjct/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle':

1. Target 'React-Core-60309c9c-AccessibilityResources' has create directory command with output '/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BehzadPhtographyProjct-hibcbeuckyuxhmdaockdldhnuyen/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BehzadPhtographyProjct/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'
2. Target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' has create directory command with output '/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BehzadPhtographyProjct-hibcbeuckyuxhmdaockdldhnuyen/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BehzadPhtographyProjct/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'

***I tried almost every solution, changes legacy, changes in pods, but still getting this error.***

Comment: Have you tried deleting all DerivedData?
You can do that by clicking `File` -> `Workspace Settings` -> Click on the tiny arrow just beside the `/path/to/DerivedData`, and Delete it.

Additionally, you can `Clean Build` by holding `Shift` + `Command` + `K`.

Comment: I already tried to delete /path/to/DerivedData but no solution. I am using push notifications in this project.

Comment: Have you tried to **Clean Build Folder**?

Comment: Maybe this should help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65083990/1682304

Comment: this one solve my problem by removing file React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources from pods folder.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Deleting React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources in the Pods project worked for me.