# Unable to Archive ReactNative project in Mac M1

Tags: ios, reactjs, swift, xcode, react-native

When I try to Archive, I get the following error -

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-giaimtwxkjihslcrnslgrczdvfrm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/project/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle':

1) Target 'React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources' has create directory command with output '/Users/kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-giaimtwxkjihslcrnslgrczdvfrm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/project/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'

2) Target 'React-Core.common-Hermes-AccessibilityResources' has create directory command with output '/Users/kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-giaimtwxkjihslcrnslgrczdvfrm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/project/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'
```

If I remove `React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources` from Pods, the share extension doesn't build stating that it needs this Pod.

Stack I am using -

```
RN - 0.64.2
React - 17.0.1
Node - 14.17.3
npm - 7.5.0
Xcode - 12.5.1
Macbook Air M1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, that I was having a different configuration of ReactNative for the share extension than the main app, which was importing the dependencies twice.

Here's a snippet from the PodFile

```
target 'project' do 
  ...
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )

  ...
end

target 'shareExtension' do
  ...
  use react_native!
  ...
end
```

For the share extension, I replaced the config with this

```
target 'shareExtesion' do
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )

  ...
end
```

After making this change in `Podfile`, do necessary cleanups, `pod install` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources` from target in `Podfile` fixed the issue.

```
...
use_flipper!
post_install do |installer|
  flipper_post_install(installer)

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
...
```

**IF THAT DIDNT WORKED TRY THIS:**

I fixed this error by deleting 'React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources' from my pod targets. When attempting to archive, make sure you are not using .xcodeproj and using your workspace. Even if you think you are using workspace triple check. Also if you try archiving through the command line you must specifically state workspace.

CREDITS:
[How to fix React Native App not building for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63082833/how-to-fix-react-native-app-not-building-for-ios)

[Xcode 12 Error: Multiple commands produce AccessibilityResources.bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040154/xcode-12-error-multiple-commands-produce-accessibilityresources-bundle)

Comment: I have a ShareExtension as well, cause my app accepts texts as Share point.
If I remove the 'React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources', ShareExtension doesn't builds.